# I can only use navigator.getCurrentPosition() once

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

So I have the below code to receive my current longitude and latitude. It works once, but when I reload the page it doesn't work anymore when I press the button. Does anyone know what is causing this?

I'm using a node.js server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Get the Location</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      function getLocation()

      {

          if (navigator.geolocation)

          {

              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successfulPosition);

          }

          else

              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your browser does not support HTML5 Geolocation";

      }

      function successfulPosition(location)

      {

          var lat = location.coords.latitude;

          var long = location.coords.longitude;

          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Latitude: " + lat +

              "<br />Longitude: " + long;

      }

  </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<button id="getPosition" onclick="getLocation();">Get Position</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Chrome browser? There seems to be a [known issue with Chrome v65](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=820945). I updated to Chrome v66 and it seems to work consistently again. Although I still can't figure out why it's so slow (takes 5-10 seconds) whereas in safari it's pretty much instant.

EDIT:

I've logged an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=844061) with the Chromium team regarding the sluggishness of the response. They've confirmed the issue and are looking into it. Let's hope for a resolution soon.